# How do I customise my x-axis to reflect the true number of participants?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph, x-axis

So I am trying to create a line graph which shows scores pre and post intervention for a number of participants. However, the number of participants does not reflect the x axis scale. For example (see picture) the x-axis goes from 2 to 7. But, I want the x axis to only show the participants who completed the questionnaires. e.g. 2,3,5,7. Does anyone know how this can be done? my code is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcLOc.png)

```
ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x = Participant)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = PRE_QUIP_RS, colour = "PRE QUIP RS")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = PRE_QUIP_RS, colour = "PRE QUIP RS")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = POST_QUIP_RS, colour = "POST QUIP RS")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = POST_QUIP_RS, colour = "POST QUIP RS")) +
  scale_colour_manual("", 
                      breaks = c("PRE QUIP RS", "POST QUIP RS"),
                      values = c("blue", "orange")) +
  xlab("Participants ") +
  scale_y_continuous("QUIP RS Scores", limits = c(0,30)) + 
  labs(title="Pre and Post QUIP RS Scores")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeYVS.png)

Comment: your data is not well structured for this. You need to restructure data to "long" format, then use `aes(group = participant)` to identify the line. Please provide a reproducible example and we can help.

Comment: Coerce the x axis variable to factor. Discrete variables are plotted consecutively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coerce `Participant` to factor. Factors are internally coded as consecutive integers, so the main question is solved.

As for the repetition of code to plot the several columns, this sort of problem is usually a data reformating problem. See [reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format).

I have simplified the column names a bit.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
})

set.seed(2022)
Participant <- c(2,3,5,7)
PRE <- sample(20:30, 4)
POST <- sample(10:20, 4)
my_data <- data.frame(Participant, PRE, POST)

my_data %>%
  pivot_longer(-Participant) %>%
  mutate(Participant = factor(Participant)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Participant, value, color = name, group = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual("", 
                      breaks = c("PRE", "POST"),
                      values = c("blue", "orange")) +
  xlab("Participants") +
  scale_y_continuous("QUIP RS Scores", limits = c(0,30)) + 
  labs(title="Pre and Post QUIP RS Scores")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much for this! you've saved me a lot of time and I understand much more now :)